# Check management server on SCOM 2012

Tags: powershell, scom

I have to check about 400 machines for the management server as we have moved from SCOM 2007 to 2012 and we need to check if the old SCOM 2007 server is still being pointed at.

On an individual server I see the following:

[image: Operations Manager Agent Properties]

I'm checking this on individual servers by opening `AgentControlPanel.exe` under `c:\program files\system center Operations management\agent`.

I'm hoping there is a PowerShell method of getting around this but I'm not having much joy on Google.

Answer (score 2):

The SCOM agent stores its config in HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Operations Manager\3.0\Agement Management Groups.

Each management group will have a subcontainer in there, which should be easy enough to test. Chances are your old and new SCOM servers will have different Management Group Names, so you should be able to just check for the existence of the old one. If you changes something in registry you need to restart the SCOM agent for the changes to take effect.

```
if (test-path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Operations Manager\3.0\Agement Management Groups\OLDMG")
{write-host "this computer is using the old SCOM server"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the old SCOM server still alive? If it is then I would just check if there are any "responding" computers in the console. That would save you tons of work.

Comment: Afraid that's gone so it isn't an option.